# The EntityFramework package is not installed on project ASP.NET Beta8

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Trying to get Entity Framework 7 to work in my ASP.NET 5 Beta8 project.  I have references to EntityFramework.SqlServer 7.0.0-beta8 and EntityFramework.Commands 7.0.0-beta8 packages in my references.

Yet when I go to the Nuget Package Manager Console and type:

```
Enable-Migrations

The EntityFramework package is not installed on project "My Project"
```

And `Add-Migration`

```
Add-Migration InitialMigration

The EntityFramework package is not installed on project "My Project"
```

The default project in the console is set to the correct project.

Comment: EntityFramework 7 detailed docs and practice examples that you can follow http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet5.html

Comment: It looks like the Entity Framework 6 commands are running... does your solution have both?

Answer (score 1):

*The migrations experience in ASP.NET 5 is still a work-in-progress. The following steps are overly complex and will be simplified by the time we reach a stable release.*

#### Now that you have a model, you can use migrations to create a database for you.

1. Open a command prompt (Windows Key + R, type cmd, click OK)
2. Use the `cd` command to navigate to the project directory
3. Run `dnvm use 1.0.0-beta8`
4. Run `dnx ef migrations add MyFirstMigration` to scaffold a migration to create the initial set of tables for your model.
5. Run `dnx ef database update` to apply the new migration to the database.

Because your database doesn’t exist yet, it will be created for you before the migration is applied.

Source: [Entity Framework 7 documentation](http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet5.html)

Answer (score 0):

No, not yet. You should use the new dnx command form the command prompt
see dnx ef --help for more information

Be sure you run dnvm use to set the correct dnx version

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Package in order to get it it working , i have resolved my issue using this.
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Version 3.1.9
as per
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations?view=aspnetcore-3.1#pmc